# Ubuntu 14.04 Variety wallpaper and the lockscreen background

Tags: desktop-background

Basically, to change the lockscreen background in Ubuntu 14.04 I run these commands:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'false'
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background 'path-to-image'
```

But it seems Variety wallpaper changer overrides these changes and places the current wallpaper into my lockscreen. Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 2):

Variety developer here.

Please note that it is the default behavior of Ubuntu to use your current wallpaper as login/lock screen background as well, depending on the paths and permissions over the image (e.g. if you use the Appearance settings to set one of the stock wallpapers, it will be set as login/lock screen background, regardless of Variety running or not). So following the steps below may or may not help you, but still give them a try:

Make sure you have unchecked the option in Customize -> Login Screen Support. Edit `~/.config/variety/scripts/set_wallpaper` and remove the line `gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background "$WP"`.

Variety does not touch the `draw-user-backgrounds` setting.

Comment: @user1214120 did it work?